# Vector in c++ error when trying to call at()

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to get a pointer to mytype of a `vector(vector mytype*)` but I get segmegation fault.
I've the following code:

```
void add(string b, vector<mytype*> *p){
    int a;
    mytype *fre=NULL;
    a=oura.front();
    oura.pop();
    if(!(p->size()<a) && oura.size()>0){
        fre=p->at(a-1); //Error seems to come from here
        add(b,fre->get_vec());
    }
    else{ ...}
    }
```

`mytype` was a class with a `string` and a `vector<mytype*>` pointer.

The error seems to come from `fre=p->at(a-1)`

`oura` is a `queue<int>` and takes values between 1-20 so i used (a-1).

Comment: Can you share a little bit of mytype class? Are you using a vector of pointers to a class witch point to other vectors?

Comment: Not the problem but `a < p->size()` is a lot easier to understand than `!(p->size()<a) `.

Comment: You have to also check that a-1 is a valid index for the array

Comment: @NathanOliver Shouldnt that be <= ?

Comment: @Borgleader It could be but instead I would also remove the `-1` from `fre=p->at(a-1);` as `<` will make sure I am not at the end.

Comment: if both p->size() and a is zero then the condition is passed, but a-1 is invalid

Comment: What is `oura`?

Comment: If `a-1` is invalid you should get an exception, not a segmentation fault. It's more likely that `p` doesn't point to a valid vector.

Comment: another problem; you pop from `oura` before checking if its empty

Comment: @molbdnilo `p` is valid cause works well on `else{...}` part.

Comment: @KakamiOkatsu My class members are one string  and a pointer to a vector.

Comment: @Siluorman C++ is rarely that simple to reason about. Undefined behaviour can appear to work perfectly well in some circumstances and not in others.

Answer (score 2):

`at` does bounds checking when accessing elements. If it's out of bounds it will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception.

adding an `assert(a > 0);` should let you find out when it happens.